# Simple Scaling/Distorting Question

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, transform

I'm working on a small project to add the note names to one of my guitar fretboards. Right now I've got all the note names laid out in a simple grid but I can't for the life of me figure out how to distort the grid to fit the neck- the neck is wider at the bottom than at the top. I've tried using the free transform tool on the group of note names but for some reason it is not giving me independent control of the corners. I tried rasterizing the group thinking that would do the trick, but no luck.

Here is a screenshot of the grid so you can get a feel for what I'm saying (the black lines mark the desired width, it is a very slight distortion).

[image: the grid]

Any help or advice would be great- Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the group of all the shapes.
- Choose `Object > Envelope Distort > make With Mesh...`
- Enter 1 Row and 1 Column and click OK
- Now you can use Free Transform to introduce perspective transformations.

Comment: Thanks Scott! This worked great. I still seemed unable to use the free transform tool, but was able to accomplish the scaling with the direct selection tool.

Comment: The Free Transform tool can be tricky, especially in versions earlier than CC (17). It takes a series of modifier keys pressed at the *right time* to work correctly.